# How to add wsa reference parameters to cxf client call?

Tags: java, cxf, ws-addressing, reference-parameters

I understand how to simply add the "standard" ws addressing headers to a cxf client call:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = ...;
factory.getFeatures().add(new WSAddressingFeature());
```

But I don't understand exactly how I could add wsa reference parameters so that the soap header of the message looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org
/2005/08 /addressing" xmlns:ns1=... >
<soap:Header>
  <wsa:To>...</wsa:To>
  <wsa:Action>...</wsa:Action>
  <wsa:MessageID>...</wsa:MessageID>
  <ns1:Country wsa:IsReferenceParameter="true">xx</ns1:Country>
  <ns1:Brand wsa:IsReferenceParameter="true">x</ns1:Brand>
</soap:Header> ...
```

How can I add this headers within a cxf client call?

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: Is it best practice to add an interceptor to the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with help of [AddressingProperties](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/ws/addressing/AddressingProperties.html).

```
factory.setServiceClass(...);
factory.setAddress(...);
factory.getFeatures().add(new WSAddressingFeature());
SomePortType client = (SomePortType) factory.create();
AddressingProperties maps = new AddressingPropertiesImpl();
EndpointReferenceType epr = new EndpointReferenceType();

//Then you can add referenceParameters to the epr
ReferenceParametersType ref = new ReferenceParametersType();
List<Object> paras = ref.getAny();
Country ctry = new Country("xx");

JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Country.class });
Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
DOMResult res = new DOMResult();
marshaller.marshal(ctry, res);
Element elt = ((Document) res.getNode()).getDocumentElement();
any.add(elt);

epr.setReferenceParameters(ref);
maps.setTo(epr);

((BindingProvider)client).getRequestContext()
    .put(JAXWSAConstants.CLIENT_ADDRESSING_PROPERTIES, maps);
```

Reference: cxf doc about ws-addr (I cannot post more links, sigh..) and http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/setting-reference-parameters-in-WS-Addressing-header-td3257262.html
I'm not familiar with JAXB, and I think their could be better way to add parameters to ref.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I've added my referenceparameters with an interceptor, however your provided answer/solution looks nicer than mine :).